# iOS : Get top colors from every pixels of an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

In my project I need to show the top three colours for an image given (look at the sample image below) . The functionality requirement is I have to get the top three colours in every pixel of an image individually then those have to be calculated for all pixels. finally top three presented colours in given image have to be listed as output . (had a look at GPUImage but i could't found any code for my requirement) .  Thanks ..

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for per-pixel colors, or general colors found in the scene? (e.g. there is a lot of green in your image, but there are actually many different pixel colors which are really close to each other.)

Comment: looking for pixel colors RGB

Comment: You mean, RGB colors that are appearing most?  If so, I'm sure it can be done, but it can take a few to several seconds, depending on the number of pixels on a picture.

Comment: yeah RGB colors of every pixels .

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function with double for-loops.  I picked up some code somebody posted here and then made some changes, I think.  I don't develop iOS any more.  So I cannot answer detailed questions.  But you should be able to get some idea out of this function.

```
- (UIColor *)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage *)image atX:(CGFloat)xx atY:(CGFloat)yy {
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0,width,height),imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    int index = 4*((width*yy)+xx);
    int R = rawData[index];
    int G = rawData[index+1];
    int B = rawData[index+2];
    UIColor *aColor;
    aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:R/255.0 green:G/255.0 blue:B/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    rValue = R; gValue = G; bValue = B;
    free(rawData);
    return aColor;
}
```

// Updated //

Example

```
UIColor *c = [self getRGBAsFromImage:colorImage1.image atX:0 atY:0]; // colorImage1 is UIImageView
```

Get image dimensions, first.  Then use double for-loop to iterate x and y values.  Then store the color value in an array for your objective.

Comment: great, and what & why the values should be passed in parameters ( atX:(CGFloat)xx atY:(CGFloat)yy )    ?

Comment: I've added further explanation.